# ASP Themes: Skin Localization

Tags: asp.net, localization, themes

Is any way to localize text in .skin file (asp.net theme)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.  Localized text comes from a resource file.  Skin files pertain to the look and feel, not content.

Comment: i know, i only trying if it is possible. But what if i want to have identically buttons on 100 pages? I think, that must exist an easier solution, than writing usercontrol/webcontrol..

Comment: The control would be easier since the code is in one place, not 100.  You could have a theme for each language but that would involve hidding ALL the other buttons.  It would get messy fast.

Comment: You're right, it would be very confused. But i'm searching simpliest solution for this cases. I was thinking about control with enum, which would represent the name of resource and skinId..

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to go down this road the easiest might be to setup a asp.net theme for each language then flip the theme based on the location. Each theme can contain buttons, skins etc for the specific language