# Is this possible to have translation resources in theme skin file in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, telerik, skin

I need move `"Hoy"` and `"Cancelar"` strings to `Resources` file for translation purposes
(I want to provide per user custom translations of Telerik controls, not build ones.)

Part of `Default.skin` file:

```
....

<telerik:RadDatePicker runat="server" >
   <Calendar>
   <FastNavigationSettings TodayButtonCaption="Hoy"
                           CancelButtonCaption="Cancelar">
   </FastNavigationSettings>
</Calendar>
....
```

Is there any possibilty to achieve that?

Comment: It is possible, I know that because we use telerik controls at work much to my disapproval. I couldn't tell you how it does the translations after that though sorry, after we generate the resource file it's all shoved into the database for translation and does some fancy stuff that I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't localize text in .skin file. A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945770/asp-themes-skin-localization).
However, maybe you can achieve what you want by importing `RadDatePicker` `resx` file in the `App_GlobalResouce` folder of your project. It works for the RadGrid and some other controls.

Comment: *You can't localize text in .skin file* is +50 worth answer. I've decided to set localisation resources for every RadDatePicker usage in apllication (with little help of strategy design pattern).

Answer (score 0):

No you should not do this the way you said. Telerik controls fully support localization and globalization so probably you should just set thread culture and UICulture and everything would work with no manual replacements of strings from your side.

Comment: Yes, but I want to provide per user custom translations of Telerik controls, not build ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this example, as it supports localization. There are many demo samples in their site.

[Demo examples](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx)

[Localization of telerik rad datepicker](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/calendar-localization-strings.html)

Comment: That's what he's doing, but I think he wants a generic way to translate and not to put it in every page.